# Am I safe with this method of penetrating shadow dom

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I have a pair of elements `<file-location>` and `<file-location-dialog>`. If the user clicks on the `<file-location>` with the intention of changing it, it fires a custom event `file-change-request` which is being listened for on its domHost by the `<file-location-dialog>` element. When it receives this request it stores the `event.path[0]` value from the request just received, pops up a dialog, gets the new location, sends of an ajax request to update the database and then fires back at the stored `event.path[0]` element a `file-location-updated` event.  The original `<file-location>` element receives this response and updates the screen accordingly with the new location.

I originally developed this because I had a set of search results (potentially up to 400) each of which had this file location.  I thought I would save on overall dom-elements by centralizing the only occasionally used dialog and ajax elements.  This has all been working fine in the search dialog.

I have recently come to develop a different page of my application where the `<file-location>` element was needed again.  However, without thinking about it, I have embedded the `<file-location>` element in the local DOM of a custom element `<pas-appointment>` whereas the `<file-location-dialog>` element sits in the custom element for the page, which uses the `<pas-appointment>` element inside a `<template is="dom-repeat">`

Again this "appears" to be working fine.

Obviously, there should be no problem with the `file-location-request` bubbling up the hierarchy of elements, but I suddenly just realised that in essence the `file-location-updated` is piercing the shadow dom as it seems to pass seamlessly through the `<pas-appointment>` boundary as though it wasn't there.

OK, so it works - so why am I asking the question?  I am developing some another elements that are going to be of a similar nature.  Before I rely on this design pattern can I be sure that it will continue to work as browsers properly implement the shadow dom specs. In particular what is likely to happen when we get to Polymer 2.0 and the web-components v1 specs?

Comment: I don't think concepts like event `bubbling` and `capturing` will have any change. As per Polymer team's vision they want web components and Polymer to be as much as possible in sync/using with current web standards. Polymer team has removed sugaring from event firing in 2.0 preview

Comment: I am sure the `bubbling` up will work.  What I am more concerned about is is the return event (`file-location-updated`) where the event target is the element at `path[0]` from the request and is inside the shadow dom of an element. Will the v1 specs allow that element to be reached.

Comment: If you check [here](http://hayato.io/2016/shadowdomv1/#v1) and [here](http://hayato.io/2016/shadowdomv1/#v1_2) it looks like `v1` has two types of shadow roots one in which it will work and one in which it will not work. Even in `open root` path value will change and `#ShadowRoot` will occupy one path value, just like it does in vo shadow-dom

Comment: yes - I have read those documents.  Since I am in control of the elements, they will have open shadowDoms.  There are still two issues.  1) I think `event.composedPath()` replaces `event.path` and whilst I think the result is the same I am finding it hard to be sure, and 2) I have found nothing which speaks about trying to dispatch an event into the shadowDom (mode open), since what I currently do is dispatch an event on `event.path[0]` and what I suspect I will have to do in the future is dispatch an event on `event.composedPath()[0]`